# Coerce Windows to show a thumbnail for my custom file type

Tags: windows-vista, windows-xp, thumbnails

I want to use the windows OpenFileDialog class in C# to browse files for my application. I would then like the files to show up with previews in Windows' "thumbnails" view.

Is there a simple way to make this happen? I'm thinking there should be a way to encode the files so that Windows simply reads and displays the thumbnail information, even though it's an unsupported file type?

I know Windows Vista has a different interface (IThumbnailProvider as opposed to IExtractImage) than Windows XP, but I need it to work across platforms.

Thanks!
/ Jakob

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to write a Shell Extension Handler Thumbnail Image Extractor.  This is unmanaged c++ code that extracts the image from your custom filetype to display within explorer shell.  You can find more about Shell Extension Handlers at the following link:

[Creating Shell Extension Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144067(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: It's more than 8 years later, has this changed any or is there a simpler way?