# Can I add a thumbnail to my custom file extension that Windows will render?

Tags: .net, registry, windows-shell

I have a c# .Net 3.5 application that creates xaml files with drawings in them. I'd like to insert a thumbnail into the file so that the user gets some indication of the file contents in  Windows Explorer.

Any ideas what approach to take?

Regards David

Comment: I think it isn't .Net question. For appling custom thumbnails you should learn how to register file type in Windows registry.

Comment: I think it's more of a shell extension task than a registry task. I found this example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguide9.aspx but I can't find anything in the managed world.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Coerce Windows to show a thumbnail for my custom file type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695411/coerce-windows-to-show-a-thumbnail-for-my-custom-file-type)