# Load from IPersistMoniker takes long time to load unresolvable URL

Tags: c++, webbrowser-control, c++builder, twebbrowser, mshtml

I am loading an local disk drive `_test.htm` file through `IPersistMoniker` `Load` method. From what I believe, it is supposed to add the path to the relative URLs as base path. Problem is - it does not do so. Instead, it takes a very long time trying to resolve the path from Internet until it gives up (about 20-30 seconds). What I want is to give up instantly, as soon as the unsolvable path is detected (since it is a local disk file anyway).

This is an example HTML I am loading:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//test/test.js"></script>
  <head>
  <body>
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <img src="/image.jpg">
    <img src="//image.jpg">
  </body>
</html>
```

Simplified code (C++ Builder) with no error checking:

```cpp
WideString      URL = "file:///" + StringReplace(ExtractFilePath(Application->ExeName), "\\", "/", TReplaceFlags() << rfReplaceAll) + "_test.htm";
TCppWebBrowser* WB  = CppWebBrowser1;

DelphiInterface<IMoniker> pMoniker;
OleCheck(CreateURLMonikerEx(NULL, URL.c_bstr(), &pMoniker, URL_MK_UNIFORM));

DelphiInterface<IHTMLDocument2> diDoc2 = WB->Document;
DelphiInterface<IPersistMoniker> pPrstMnkr;
OleCheck(diDoc2->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistMoniker, (LPVOID*)&pPrstMnkr));

DelphiInterface<IBindCtx> pBCtx;
OleCheck(CreateBindCtx(0, &pBCtx));

pPrstMnkr->Load(0, pMoniker, pBCtx, STGM_READWRITE);
```

Problem - `image.jpg` loads fine, but the paths `//test/test.js` and `/image.jpg` and `//image.jpg` take a very long time to resolve/load. From what I understand `CreateURLMonikerEx` is supposed to use `file:///path/to/executable/` and prepend that automatically to these paths in which case they would fail instantly - `file:///path/to/executable//test/test.js` for example. That does not happen.

I additionally tried to move `image.jpg` to a subfolder and then create custom `IMoniker` interface with the `GetDisplayName` and `BindToStorage` implementation which loaded the image from a custom path. However it doesn't do the same for paths which start with `//` or `/`. Even though I output `file:///path/to/executable/` in the `GetDisplayName` through the `*ppszDisplayName` parameter.

How can I avoid extended time loading such unusable links (discard them), or redirect them to local path as above?

I found a partial solution to use `about:blank` in the `*ppszDisplayName` but then it doesn't load images with the valid path `image.jpg` as then it loads them as `about:image.jpg` which again is invalid path.

Additionally - I've tried adding `IDocHostUIHandler` interface with the implementation of `Invoke` method (`DISPID_AMBIENT_DLCONTROL`) with the `pVarResult->lVal = DLCTL_NO_SCRIPTS | DLCTL_NO_JAVA | DLCTL_NO_RUNACTIVEXCTLS | DLCTL_NO_DLACTIVEXCTLS | DLCTL_NO_FRAMEDOWNLOAD | DLCTL_FORCEOFFLINE;` - it it blocks the download of images entirely, but still does check 20-30 seconds for the links starting with `//` or `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Update - this doesn't work well!**
>
> The code below doesn't work well! The problem is - it loses `<BODY>`
> tag attributes. BODY tag turns out entirely empty after loading. I
> ended up loading the message using `IHTMLDocument2.write` method.
>
> See: [Assigning IHTMLDocument2 instance to a TWebBrowser instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69554315/assigning-ihtmldocument2-instance-to-a-twebbrowser-instance)

After spending lots of time and no guidance of any kind here, I believe that it is not possible to avoid this wait 20-30 sec when the links are invalid. I found another solution and if someone wants to supplement this solution, feel free to do so.

Instead what I had to do is to create an instance of `CLSID_HTMLDocument` (`IHTMLDocument3` or `IHTMLDocument2` interface) and then load the document into that container and parse the links prior to doing anything with them. This is described on:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa703592(v=vs.85)

This also helped:

[How to load html contents from stream and then how to create style sheet to display the html file in preview pane (like HTML preview handler)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909747/how-to-load-html-contents-from-stream-and-then-how-to-create-style-sheet-to-disp)

After parsing the document URLs and fixing the invalid ones, it can be saved/displayed in the actual `TWebBrowser`.

Rough solution (C++ Builder):

```cpp
try
    {
    DelphiInterface<IHTMLDocument2> diDoc2;
    OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_HTMLDocument, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IHTMLDocument2, (void**)&diDoc2));

    DelphiInterface<IPersistStreamInit> diPersist;
    OleCheck(diDoc2->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistStreamInit, (void**)&diPersist));
    OleCheck(diPersist->InitNew());

    DelphiInterface<IMarkupServices> diMS;
    OleCheck(diDoc2->QueryInterface(IID_IMarkupServices, (void**)&diMS));

    DelphiInterface<IMarkupPointer> diMkStart;
    DelphiInterface<IMarkupPointer> diMkFinish;

    OleCheck(diMS->CreateMarkupPointer(&diMkStart));
    OleCheck(diMS->CreateMarkupPointer(&diMkFinish));

    // ...Load from file or memory stream into your WideString here...

    DelphiInterface<IMarkupContainer> diMC;
    OleCheck(diMS->ParseString(WideString(MsgHTMLSrc).c_bstr(), 0, &diMC, diMkStart, diMkFinish));

    DelphiInterface<IHTMLDocument2> diDoc;
    OleCheck(diMC->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&diDoc)));

    DelphiInterface<IHTMLElementCollection> diCol;
    OleCheck(diDoc->get_all(&diCol));

    long ColLen = 0;
    OleCheck(diCol->get_length(&ColLen));

    for (int i = 0; i < ColLen; ++i)
        {
        DelphiInterface<IDispatch> diItem;
        diCol->item(OleVariant(i), OleVariant(i), &diItem);

        DelphiInterface<IHTMLElement> diElem;
        OleCheck(diItem->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLElement, (void**)&diElem));

        WideString wTagName;
        OleCheck(diElem->get_tagName(&wTagName));

        if (StartsText("img", wTagName))
            {
            OleVariant vSrc;
            OleCheck(diElem->getAttribute(OleVariant("src"), 4, vSrc));

            // Make changes to vSrc here....

            // And save it back to src
            OleCheck(diElem->setAttribute(OleVariant("src"), vSrc, 0));
            }
        else if (StartsText("script", wTagName)) 
            {
            // More parsing here...
            }
        }
    }
catch (EOleSysError& e)
    {
    // Process exception as needed
    }
catch (Exception& e)
    {
    // Process exception as needed
    }
```

After full parsing of all required elements (`img`/`src`, `script`/`src`, `base`/`href` etc.) save and load into `TWebBrowser`.

I only now have to see if the parsed HTML `IHTMLDocument2` can be directly assigned to `TWebBrowser` without loading it again, but that is another question (See - [Assigning IHTMLDocument2 instance to a TWebBrowser instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69554315/assigning-ihtmldocument2-instance-to-a-twebbrowser-instance))