# Assigning IHTMLDocument2 instance to a TWebBrowser instance

Tags: delphi, c++builder, mshtml, ihtmldocument2, ihtmldocument

I am using an instance of the `IHTMLDocument2` interface to parse some HTML as described in this post:

[Load from IPersistMoniker takes long time to load unresolvable URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69516437/load-from-ipersistmoniker-takes-long-time-to-load-unresolvable-url)

The code is relatively simple:

```
DelphiInterface<IHTMLDocument2> diDoc2;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_HTMLDocument, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IHTMLDocument2, (LPVOID*)&diDoc2);
// Load and process HTML here and save into memory stream or to disk after the processing is done
```

When I am done I save the HTML contents of the newly modified `diDoc2` above and load the HTML into `TWebBrowser`.

1. Can I instead just "assign" the already parsed `IHTMLDocument2` above directly to the `IHTMLDocument2` contained in the `TWebBrowser`, which seems would be much faster way of doing it. I can use probably `IHTMLDocument2.write` or some other method to do so, but there would be likely some performance penalty than simply assigning a pointer to already initialized object, if that is possible in the first place. In other words, I simply want to "show"/"render" what I have just parsed in the "back buffer" of sort.
2. Is there a need to call `CoInitialize` and `CoUninitialize` before and after calling `CoCreateInstance`? I've seen some code which does that but it works without it, unless Delphi/C++ Builder do some under-the-hood initialization.

Comment: 1) not directly, no. But you can query the browser's `IHTMLDocument2` for `IPersistStream/Init` and give it prepared data through that. 2) yes, `CoInitialize()`/`CoUninitilize()` are required, however the RTL calls them for you in the main UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `IHTMLDocument2.write` and it appears to work well.

```cpp
WideString HTML = "<html><body>test</body></html>";
if (diDoc)
    {
    // Creates a new one-dimensional array
    SAFEARRAY *psaStrings = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_VARIANT,0,1);

    if (psaStrings)
        {
        VARIANT *param;
        BSTR bstr = SysAllocString(HTML.c_bstr());
        SafeArrayAccessData(psaStrings, (LPVOID*)&param);
        param->vt      = VT_BSTR;
        param->bstrVal = bstr;
        SafeArrayUnaccessData(psaStrings);
        diDoc->write(psaStrings);
        diDoc->close();

        // SafeArrayDestroy calls SysFreeString for each BSTR
        //SysFreeString(bstr);  // SafeArrayDestroy should be enough
        SafeArrayDestroy(psaStrings);

        return S_OK;
        }
    }

return E_FAIL;
```